# seperate Weight from Weight/bias vector neural network Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have trained neural network by matlab nntraintool 
i want to have weights and bias. i have tried these function to get them

wb = formwb(net,net.b,net.iw,net.lw)
[b,iw,lw] = separatewb(net,wb)

wb =

-28.5243
   26.1019
   10.2387
   23.7000
  -12.2929
   14.6831
   16.7075
  -26.4566
    9.4643
  -24.0166
  -26.8963 ...

b =

```
[20x1 double]
[     0.0411]
```

iw =

```
[20x1 double]
[]
```

lw =

```
           []    []
[1x20 double]    []
```

can some one help me how to read them

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is after executing these two commands:

> > wb = formwb(net,net.b,net.iw,net.lw);
> >
> > [b,iw,lw] = separatewb(net,wb);

look inside your workspace, then double-click any of these variables (b, iw, lw) and then again double-click on those cells that say [# x # double]..

Comment: I edited your answer. In SO answer and questions are not signed (less noise) :-).